# Dealing with extremely imbalance with xgboost

Tags: xgboost, imbalanced-data

My training data has extremely class imbalanced

```
{0:872525,1:3335}
```

with 100 features.
I use `xgboost` to build classification model with Bayesian optimisation to hypertune the model in range

```
{ learning rate:(0.001,0.1), 
  min_split_loss:(0.10), 
  max_depth:(3,70), 
  min_child_weight:(1:20), 
  max_delta_step:(1,20), 
  subsample:(0:1),  
  colsample_bytree:(0.5,1), 
  lambda:(0,10), 
  alpha:(0,10), 
  scale_pos_weight:(1,262), 
  n_estimator:(1,20)
}
```

I also use `binary:logistics` as the objective model and `roc_auc` as the metrics with booster `gbtree`.
The cross validation score is 82.5%.
However, when I implemented the model to the testing data I got a score of only

```
Roc_auc: 75.2%, 
pr_auc: 15%, 
log_loss: 0.046
```

and confusion matrix:

```
[[19300 7],
[103 14]]
```

I need help to find the best way to increase the true positive to be around 60% with tolerance false positive until 3 times actual positive.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages, along with "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)". Properly formatting your question helps us help you, and helps others understand what your question is about when they're looking for a solution also. Also read "[mre]". We need example code that runs and demonstrates the problem you're having. As is, it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your dataset is very imbalanced.

I'd recommend looking at "[imbalanced-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn)", which is

> a python package offering a number of re-sampling techniques commonly used in datasets showing strong between-class imbalance.

These techniques include, for example, over and under sampling.

You can find out more in the [full documentation and examples](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/).

If you are working on this dataset in a company, you can also investigate getting more data or pruning your dataset using rules/heuristics.

Comment: I know the oversampling method, however my data is 750k rows with 320 features now so I prefer class weight to prevent the increasing rows. Do you have any other idea? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/92776/high-recall-but-too-low-precision-result-in-imbalanced-data

Comment: Without having context about the business problem, it's a bit tough to give further recommendations. E.g., sometimes you can balance a dataset by reframing the problem - which could allow you to remove some instances based on rules. Inspecting your data is a great way to start.

Comment: See "[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)".